# How Apple did the new iOS6 app store details view?

Tags: ios, user-interface

If you open up the new iOS App Store, and tap into any of the apps, how did Apple achieve that entire view?

My guess is that it's a table view, but then how did they make the screen shots able to scroll sideways like that?

How would you do that in the most graphically efficient way without performance issues?

Comment: Put a side-scrolling subview inside your main view.

Comment: Right but how did they dynamiclly have the long description in there?  I mean if there are very long description they did not put an extra scrolling view, but to expand it to maximum size.

Comment: likely a UIPageViewController for the side-to-side scrolling, check the WWDC 2012 video that describes this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imitate the combined horizontal and vertical scrolling in the iOS iTunes store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428615/imitate-the-combined-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-in-the-ios-itunes-store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the iOS 6 UICollectionView control.  It's new to iOS 6.

There are WWDC 2012 videos in iTunes where they demonstrate exactly this effect (plus many others). There are also code examples.

Comment: I was referring to when after you tap an app. But, yeah the front page of the catalog may use it, but I think they just used a tableview + scrollview with paging enabled.  Collections is an interesting angle.