# Imitate the combined horizontal and vertical scrolling in the iOS iTunes store

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

I'm trying to create a screen similar to that in the new iTunes store:

[image: Apple iTunes App Screenshot]

That is, a grid that's scrollable both horizontally and vertically.

The first approach I've tried involved creating a `UITableView` (for the vertical rows) and, within each `UITableViewCell` of that `UITableView`, another `UITableView` that's rotated 90 degrees.

This seems to work visually but I'm not able to scroll vertically. I believe the gesture recognizers from the subview tables are preventing the gesture recognizers from the parent table view from receiving touch events.

Basically, the rows scroll horizontally but not vertically.

The next approach I've thought then is to create `UISrollView`s for each row but I was wondering if there's something I've missed?

Has anyone else encountered this issue in the past?

Comment: They possibly used the new `UICollectionView` (as of iOS 6). Unfortunately, it's still under NDA.

Comment: @mAu Don't know about iOS 6, but wasn't the AppStore and iTunes pure HTML so far?

Comment: @JustSid I'm not sure about iTunes but the app store still seems to be mostly HTML in iOS 6

Comment: I think you might be right about the iTunes store being HTML but I'd like to create the same effect using UIKit components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar to what you have with table view inside a table view, I made the rotated 90° table view the parent instead. I think I also had to turn off scrolling for one table views when scrolling is detected in the other table view, and visa-versa.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - could you talk me through how you approached turning on/off the scrolling?

Comment: I just implemented the UIScrollView delegate methods for begin dragging  and ended deceleration, I had to do this because there was an ugly issue where horizontal scrolling would end with the vertical scroll view jumping up or down at the end of deceleration.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - I'll look into the UIScroll delegate methods and see what I can come up with!

Answer (score 2):

If your trying to target below iOS 6.0, ruling out using the UICollectionView, I would try using GMGridView:

https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

It's very complete and has many features. It also has horizontal paging support which may achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205).

Comment: That would be perfect but I need to support iOS versions back to 4.3 - thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Never tried to build something like that but... Idea :

One tableview, n-cell, each cell embed a scrollView wich can contains, n-subviews.